# The getter 'size' was called on null

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

when i press the ***Telefon ile Giriş Yap*** button getting this error. App still working how i want. i cant get why getting this error. while getting this error with ***Telefon ile Giriş Yap*** button, dont get this one when press ***Google ile Giriş Yap*** button though both of them coded in similar form. here is my code:

```
//ekkran yetmeme problemi var!!!!

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:sby_cpal_demo/Helpers/AtaWidget.dart';
import 'package:sby_cpal_demo/Helpers/SignInProvider.dart';
import 'package:sby_cpal_demo/Pages/SinifListeleriPage.dart';
import 'package:sby_cpal_demo/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter_signin_button/flutter_signin_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter_signin_button/button_list.dart';

class GirisPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return GirisPageState();
  }
}

class GirisPageState extends State<GirisPage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _schoolNoController = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  bool _success;
  String _message;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      //resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Icon(Icons.account_box),
        title: Text("GİRİŞ"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            onPressed: () {
              if(AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi == "" || AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi == " "
              || AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi == null ){
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog(title: Text("*UYARI: "), content: Text("Kayıt yada giriş işlemi "
                    "tamamlanmandan sayfadan çıkmak üzeresiniz!!", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),),
                  actions: [
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Text("Yine de Çık"), color: Colors.green,
                      onPressed: (){
                        AtaWidget.of(context).kayitadi = null;
                        goToMyHomePage();
                        Navigator.of(context,rootNavigator: true).pop("dialog");
                        },
                    ),
                ],);
                showDialog(context: context, builder: (_)=> alertDialog);
              } else { goToMyHomePage(); }
            },
          ),
          Builder(
            builder: (context)=>IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.logout), onPressed: ()async{
              await _auth.signOut();
              setState(() {
                AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi = " ";
                AtaWidget.of(context).kullanicimail = " ";
                _success = null;
                AtaWidget.of(context).personelGiris = false;
                AtaWidget.of(context).ogrenciGiris = false;
              });
              if (await GoogleSignIn().isSignedIn()) {
                print("google user");
                await GoogleSignIn().disconnect();
                await GoogleSignIn().signOut();
              }
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()));
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Text("Başarıyla çıkış yapıldı"),
              ));
            }),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 36.0, right: 36),
              child: ListView(
               // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 30,),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.warning_amber_rounded, color: Colors.red[500], size: 30),
                    title: Text("Google ile direkt giriş yapabilirsiniz. İlk giriş için erişim izni istenebilir.",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 17, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                  ),
                  Visibility(visible: AtaWidget.of(context).personelGiris,
                    child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.phone_rounded, color: Colors.black,), backgroundColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
                        label: Text("Telefon ile giriş yap", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      onPressed: () async {

                        Widget setupAlertDialogContainer() {
                          return Container(
                            height: 300, width: 300,
                            child: StreamBuilder(
                                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("kadro_ogrt").orderBy("sıra").snapshots(),
                                builder: (context, snapshot){
                                  final _querySnapshot = snapshot.data;
                                  return ListView.builder(
                                      itemCount: _querySnapshot.size,
                                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                                        final map = _querySnapshot.docs[index].data();
                                        return Column(
                                          children: [
                                            ListTile(
                                               title: Text(map["isim"],
                                                   style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
                                               onTap: (){
                                                 Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop('dialog');
                                                _signInWithPhone(map["tel"], map["isim"]);
                                                },),
                                            Divider(thickness: 1,),]);
                                      });
                                }),
                          );
                        }
                        showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: Text("PERSONEL LİSTESİ"),
                            content: setupAlertDialogContainer(),
                          );
                        });

                    }),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  
                  SignInProvider(
                      infoText: "Google ile giriş yap",
                      buttonType: Buttons.Google,
                      signInMethod: () async {

                          Widget setupAlertDialogContainer() {
                            return Container(
                              height: 500, width: 300,
                              child: StreamBuilder(
                                  stream: AtaWidget.of(context).personelGiris == true ?
                                  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("kadro_ogrt").orderBy("sıra").snapshots()
                                  : FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("siniflar").snapshots(),

                                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                      );
                                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                      return Center(child: Icon(Icons.error, size: 40),
                                      );
                                    } else if (snapshot.data == null) {
                                      return Center( child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                      );
                                    }
                                    final querySnapshot = snapshot.data;

                                    if(AtaWidget.of(context).personelGiris == true){
                                      return ListView.builder(
                                          itemCount: querySnapshot.size,
                                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                                            final map = querySnapshot.docs[index].data();
                                            return Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  ListTile(
                                                    title: Text(map["isim"],
                                                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
                                                    onTap: ()async{
                                                      if(map["mail"] == "" || map["mail"] == " " || map["mail"] == null ){
                                                        Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop('dialog');
                                                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog(
                                                          title: Text("Hata: "), content: Text("Güvenlik sebeiyle Google ile giriş "
                                                            "yapabilmeniz için sisteme kayıtlı bir gmail hesabınız olmalıdır. Telefonla "
                                                            "giriş yaptıktan sonra GMAİL adresinizi **KADROMUZ** bölümünden kendi "
                                                            "sayfanıza ekleyerek Google ile girişi kullanabilirsiniz."),
                                                        );
                                                        showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => alertDialog);
                                                      } else {
                                                        Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop('dialog');
                                                        _signInWithGoogle(map["mail"], map["isim"]);
                                                      }
                                                    },),
                                                  Divider(thickness: 1,),]);
                                          });
                                    } else {
                                      return GridView.builder(
                                          shrinkWrap: true,
                                          itemCount: querySnapshot.size,
                                          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                              mainAxisSpacing: 10, crossAxisSpacing: 10, crossAxisCount: 3),
                                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                            final map = querySnapshot.docs[index].data();
                                            final id = querySnapshot.docs[index].id;
                                            return Container(
                                              color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                              child: GestureDetector(
                                                onTap: ()async{
                                                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>
                                                      SinifListeleriPage(map: map, id: id)));
                                                },
                                                child: GridTile(
                                                  child: Center(
                                                    child: Text(map["sinif"], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
                                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          });
                                    }

                                  }),
                            );
                          }
                          showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) {
                            return AlertDialog(
                              title: Text("SINIF LİSTESİ"),
                              content: setupAlertDialogContainer(),
                            );
                          });
                        } , // TODO: Google ile giriş
                    ),

                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(_success == null ? '' : _message ?? '',
                          style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.yellow, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 17, color: Colors.black),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                      ),
                    )
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //! Widget kapatıldığında controllerları temizle
    _schoolNoController.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  

// *****HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR*****
  void _signInWithPhone(String no, String isim) async {
    if (AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi == "" || AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi == " " ||
        AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi == null ) {

      _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: no, timeout: Duration(seconds: 120),
        verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential credential) async {
          final UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
          final User user = userCredential.user;

          setState(() {
            AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi = isim;
          });
          debugPrint("atawidget: " + AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi);
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage(),));
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
          setState(() {
            _message = e.toString();
            _success = false;
          });
        },
        codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) async {
          // Update the UI - wait for the user to enter the SMS code
          String smsCode = 'xxxx';

          // Create a PhoneAuthCredential with the code
          PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider
              .credential(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);

          // Sign the user in (or link) with the credential
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
          // Auto-resolution timed out...
        },
      );
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _message = "*HATA: Önce uygulamadan çıkış yapmalısınız.";
        _success = false;
      });
    }
  }


  
  _signInWithGoogle(String mail, String isim) async{
    if (AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi == "" || AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi == " " ||
        AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi == null ) {

      try {
        final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
        final GoogleAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
            accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth.idToken
        );
        final UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        final User user = userCredential.user;
        debugPrint(user.email.toString());

        if(user.email.toString() == mail){
          AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi = isim;
          debugPrint("atawidget: "+AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi);
          setState(() {});
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> MyHomePage(),));
        } else {
          AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Hata: "), content: Text("Seçilen kullanıcı adı ile sistemde kayıtlı mail adresi uyuşmamaktadır. "
              "Lütfen kullanıcı adını doğru seçtiğinizden emin olunuz. "),
          );
          showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) => alertDialog);
          await _auth.signOut();
          setState(() {
            AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi = " ";
            AtaWidget.of(context).kullanicimail = " ";
          });
          if (await GoogleSignIn().isSignedIn()) {
            print("google user");
            await GoogleSignIn().disconnect();
            await GoogleSignIn().signOut();
          }
        }
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
        setState(() {
          _message = e.toString();
          _success = false;
          AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi = " ";
        });
      } catch (e) {
        setState(() {
          _message = e.toString();
          _success = false;
          AtaWidget.of(context).kullaniciadi = " ";
        });
      }
    }
    else {
      setState(() {
        _message = "*HATA: Önce uygulamadan çıkış yapmalısınız.";
        _success = false;
      });
  }
  }

  void goToMyHomePage() async {
    await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()));
  }

  void goToGirisPage() async {
    await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GirisPage()));
  }

  
}
```

i know this is so long to have a look sory about that. here is my terminal output:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#12628):
The getter 'size' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: size

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> file:///C:/ornekler/sby_cpal_demo/lib/Pages/GirisPage.dart:242:36
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      GirisPageState.build.<anonymous closure>.setupAlertDialogContainer.<anonymous closure> (package:sby_cpal_demo/Pages/GirisPage.dart:247:65)
#2      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:525:81)
#3      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:129:48)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4744:28)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data from snapshot is not made available instantly, You would have to check snapshot Connection state before showing the Widget that uses the data from the snapshot, check if the snapshot has data with the snippet below before rendering the widget that needs the snapshot data.

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
//Your Widget here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe problem is here:

```
    ListView.builder(
                                      
    itemCount: _querySnapshot.size,
```

In your code _querySnapshot is `snapshot.data` data has `length` try to change it on length.